# JQuery css for table, method contains

Tags: jquery, html, css

After pressing the button, I want to append green color to all table rows, which contains yes in the 3th < td>.

This is my jQuery part:

```
 <script>
     $(button).click(function(){
            if($("tr td:nth-child(3)").contains("yes"))
                $append("myClass").css("background-color", "green");

     });
    </script>
```

This is the html part:

```
<table style="border: 2px solid black">
    <tr class="myClass">
        <td >name</td>
        <td >surname</td>
        <td>yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myClass">
        <td >name</td>
        <td >surname</td>
        <td>no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myClass">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>surname</td>
        <td >yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains()` selector to find out an element which contains a particular text.

Then use `closest("tr")` to find the parent `tr` of the corresponding `td`

```
$("tr td:nth-child(3):contains('yes')").closest("tr").css("color", "green")
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y544g7qx/5/)

Comment: It doesn't work just like this. Can you explain in details?

Answer (score 0):

CSS is probably the way to go here, but I alway feel a bit weird about using css to check the value of nodes.

If you want to use Jquery you can do the following:

$("button").click(function(){

```
 var nodes = $('tr td:nth-child(3)')
 nodes.each(function(){
   if($(this).text() === 'yes')
   {
     $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color','green');
   }
 });
```

});

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dkxuu200/)

Comment: worth noting I use parents here but closest will also suffice ( parents will keep searching 'up' the dom tree, but doesn't check against the td node, whereas closest includes the td node).  trivial difference in this case, but in a larger doc you're going to probably want closest if you are only concerned about the immediate parent